# Calculate the terms of series for $\sin^2 x$ up to and including the $x^6$ term

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate the terms of series for $\sin^2 x$ from $\sin x$ and multiplying out the terms just like multiplication of polynomials.

Comment: Which series?  $\ \ $

Comment: Should be tayler series and should set it up like e^a * e^b which I don't understand the meaning...

Comment: I suggest that you start by writing down the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$, up to and including the $x^6$ term. The result is a polynomial. If you multiply this polynomial by itself, what can you say about the result?

Comment: I don't think that will be right, first I'm looking for sin ^2 (x), also I don't understand how this thing going to fit in the e^a * e^b form

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+O(x^7)
$$
Then 
$$
\sin^2x=(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+O(x^7))^2=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{2x^6}{45}+O(x^{8})
$$
Where we have just multiplied $(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{5!})^2$ like a polynomial.

Comment: Don't you need to use the $x^5$ term because $x^5 * x$ will be $x^6$, so we need to add that in, which you don't do.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \sin x &= x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots \\
  \sin^2 x &= \left( x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots \right)^2 \\
  &= x\left( x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\ldots \right)-
  \frac{x^3}{6}\left( x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\ldots \right)+
  \frac{x^6}{120}-\ldots \\
  &= x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{2x^6}{45}-\ldots
\end{align*}

> Check with the identity $$\sin^2 x=\dfrac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$

Comment: Is this the e^a * e^b form?

Comment: Is it required to use $\sin x=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ in your text?  Then $$\sin^2 x=\left( \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \right)^2=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}}{4}$$ that'll be what I mentioned in the yellow box.